# How to return multiple fields from a Model object?

Tags: python, django

I am doing testing in django and already created a model instance using ddf.G. Now I want to use this instance in a test case to return multiple fields of the model. I know how to return multiple fields using queryset like:

```
model_values = models.User.objects.values_list(
                   'first_name', 'last_name', 'image__name', 'image__description'
               )
```

Now I want to return same fields but by using the instance I already have. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a tuple with the values you need?

`return (model.first_name, model.last_name, model.image__name, model.image__description)`